# Help editing Graphics primitives in a variable

Tags: list-manipulation, graphics

I have a variable `pent` with an `InputForm` like below and I would like to drop selected `{RGBColor[rgb],Polygon[{pointarray}]},` say {3,5} but retain the `Rotate`s and `Transform` and their parameters. Is that possible?

```
pent=
  Rotate[
    Rotate[
      Translate[{
        {RGBColor[rgb], Polygon[pointarray]}, 
        {RGBColor[rgb], Polygon[pointarray]}, 
        {RGBColor[rgb], Polygon[pointarray]}, 
        {RGBColor[rgb], Polygon[pointarray]}, 
        {RGBColor[rgb], Polygon[pointarray]}, 
        {RGBColor[rgb], Polygon[pointarray]}, 
        {RGBColor[rgb], Polygon[pointarray]}, 
        {RGBColor[rgb], Polygon[pointarray]}, 
        {RGBColor[rgb], Polygon[pointarray]}, 
        {RGBColor[rgb], Polygon[pointarray]}, 
        {RGBColor[rgb], Polygon[pointarray]}}, 
      {#,#,#}], 
    #,{#,#,#}], 
  #,{#,#,#}]
```

Here's the actual data. [pent InputForm](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7a1k65bbhtg3rfg/pent.txt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Graphics3D[pent]
```

[image]

**1.** [`ReplaceAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html)

```
pent2 = pent /. pat : {{_?ColorQ, _Polygon} ..} :> Drop[pat, {3, 5}];

Graphics3D @ pent2
```

[image]

**2.** [`MapAt`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapAt.html) + [`Nothing`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nothing.html)

```
Graphics3D[MapAt[Nothing &, pent, {1, 1, 1, 3 ;; 5}]]
```

[image]

**3.** [`MapAt`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapAt.html) + [`Drop`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Drop.html)

```
Graphics3D[MapAt[Drop[#, {3, 5}] &, pent, {1, 1, 1}]]
```

[image]

**4.** Modify `Part`s directly:

```
pent4 = pent;
pent4[[1, 1, 1, 3 ;; 5]] = {};

Graphics3D[pent4]
```

[image]

**Note:** You can use the same approaches to modify parts of `pent`. For example,

```
pent3 = pent /.  pat : {{_?ColorQ, _Polygon} ..} :> 
    MapAt[# /. x_?ColorQ -> Yellow &, pat, {3;;5}];

Graphics3D @ pent3
```

[image]

Comment: This is excellent! Thank you for your answer. I have so much to learn here.